# Error while loading JSON data with ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am getting the following error :

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>   {"users":[{"name":"A Lindsay","active":true,"id":"","login":"alindsa

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "name": "A Lindsay",
        "active": true,
        "id": "",
        "login": "alindsay@hial.co.uk",
        "email": "alindsay@hial.co.uk"
    }]
}
```

How do I get this JSON?

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlanw,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Name:" + data.name + "act:" + data.active + "nlocation:" + data.login);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name`, `active` and `login` properties are all in the `users` array, so you need to access them via the index from the `users` property, like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log("Name:" + data.users[0].name + " act:" + data.users[0].active + " nlocation:" + data.users[0].login);
}
```

Note that this will only retrieve details from the first returned `user` object. If you expect there to be multiple users returned then you would need to use a loop to iterate over them all.

Comment: Same issue:SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"users": [

Comment: In that case it sounds like the JSON you're returning isn't in a valid format. Check the exact response text in the console

Comment: users
 
 [Object { name="A Lindsay",  active=true,  login="alindsay@hial.co.uk",  meer...}, Object { name="A Macinnes",  active=true,  login="AMacinnes@hial.co.uk",  meer...}, Object { name="A. Hoek",  active=true,  login="info@hoekbrandveiligheid.nl",  meer...}, 440 meer...]
0
 
 Object { name="A Lindsay",  active=true,  login="alindsay@hial.co.uk",  meer...}
1
 
 Object { name="A Macinnes",  active=true,  login="AMacinnes@hial.co.uk",  meer...}
2
 
 Object { name="A. Hoek",  active=true,  login="info@hoekbrandveiligheid.nl",  meer...}